# NPR One API - 401 error

Tags: http-status-code-401, npr-api

I'm building an app that uses the [NPR One API](http://dev.npr.org/api/). I'm having trouble getting a response, and there aren't any posts on this topic as far as I've seen.

I used the [npr-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npr-api) node module to generate an access token, and that process seemed to work without problems. When I make a GET request at `https://api.npr.org/stationfinder/v2/organizations`, I keep getting a 401 error. I'm following the documentation and including the authorization header as specified:

```
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
```

where I've replaced "ACCESS_TOKEN" with the code generated by following the steps listed in the `npr-api` module documentation. The response body is:

```
{
  “version”: “1.0”,
  “href”: “http://api.npr.org/stationfinder/v2/organizations”,
  “attributes”: {},
  “items”: [],
  “links”: {},
  “errors”: [
    {
      “code”: 401885,
      “text”: “Unauthorized”
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried running the “Try it out!” test from the detailed API notes for **stationfinder**, which also gives me the same response.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you are working on developing an app with the NPR One API! The endpoint that you referenced, /v2/organizations, is part of a new service whose output will be changing drastically over the next month or two. For that reason, NPR is currently restricting access to this endpoint, which is why your access token is returning a 401 response. You can read more in the documentation's implementation notes here: http://dev.npr.org/api/#!/stationfinder/searchOrganizations

Developers will be given access to v3 when it is released (release is planned within the next two months).

Best,
Sarah

Comment: Thanks for the information - I didn't see that note in the midst of the documentation. Can you advise whether any of the v2 endpoints are currently active?

Comment: Yes, the endpoints for the authorization, listening, and identity services should all be accessible to you with your access token. You can reference our narrative documentation here to learn more about how to interact with these services to build your app: http://dev.npr.org/guide/services/

Comment: Thanks! It would be helpful for you to list which services are active in the [API reference](http://dev.npr.org/api/) at the top of the page, so that it's easy to see right away.